# Slick slider в модальном окне

Tags: jquery, плагин, slick.js

Имеется два слайдера slick: один основной для показа товара, второй слайдер ниже с  навигационными плитками thumbnail снизу (т.е. у двух слайдеров есть свойство asNavFor).
При нажатии на большое изображение товара, должно появится модальное окно magnific popup, в котором находится такой же похожий слайдер с thumbnail, немного по другому стилизован.
Не удалось воспроизвести пример в jsfiddle, потому-что сайт на фреймворке, а там куча зависимостей.
Проблема в том, что при открытии модального окна, ширина первого слайда меньше, чем ширина контейнера.  А если прокрутить на следующий слайд, тогда слайды нормально выравниваются на всю ширину.
Пытался применить `$('.slider-main').slick('setPosition');` чтобы выровнять слайды, но это не помогло.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема? Почему у первого слайда ширина не соответствует контейнеру?

```
_html.prototype.
    mfpAjax = function(selector) {
    selector = selector || '.js-mfp-ajax';
    $('body').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        delegate: selector,
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'zoom-in',
        callbacks: {


            ajaxContentAdded: function() {
                var $content = this.content || [];
                if ( $content.length ) {
                    _self.slickHidden( $content );
                }

                _self.formValidation( $content );
            }
        }
    });
};

_html.prototype.slickHidden = function() {
    //     //Слайдер товара
    $('.js-hidden-slider-main').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        asNavFor: '.js-hidden-slider-nav',
        arrows: false
    });

    $('.js-hidden-slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 7,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: false,
        arrows: true,
        asNavFor: '.js-hidden-slider-main',
        focusOnSelect: true
    });
    // setTimeout(function(){
    $('.js-hidden-slider-main').slick('setPosition');
    $('.js-hidden-slider-nav').slick('setPosition');
    // },200);
}
```

_html это объект-хелпер, но не в нём проблема.
Выше примерный код вызова слайдера

Comment: а setPosition вызываете при загрузке страницы или при открытии попапа?

Comment: @Cheg, обновил ответ

Comment: попробуйте вызывать setposition после открытия попапа. или вообще вызывать сам слайдер после попапа

Comment: @Cheg, а как это реализовать? т.е. как вызвать после попапа?  Я привёл код magnificpopup. Как вы посоветуете в этом коде вызывать слайдер после попап?

Comment: @Cheg, проблему решает только задержка с помощью settimeout, но даже с задержкой видно, что изначально ширина меньше, потом через долю секунду ширина слайда принимает всю ширину, что заметно на глаз и не совсем красиво. Подскажите пожалуйста, может есть какой-то более универсальный слайдер?

Answer (score 1):

`magnic popup` окно с начала имеет `display:none`.
 `slick` не может нормально инициализироваться (рассчитать свои размеры) при таких условиях, нужно либо другой попап, или залезть в плагин и скрыть окно другими способами, но не `display:none`, всё сработает.
Либо инициализировать Слик после открытия попапа...

Answer (score 0):

Просто делай инициализацию слайдера при появлении попапа. Например:

```
$('.btn--contacts').click(function() {
    $('.modal--contacts').fadeIn();
     $(".slider__contacts").slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        dots: true,
      })
});
```